Why does this error occur without any changes today : Type 'Player' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Just reloaded an exercise project which was working and now it shows me this error

Symbol.iterator


Here is a part of the component.ts in photograph,
I'm lost, can someone help me ?
Added dom.iterable in the tsconfig lib but no changes

Please never post code as screenshot, see the formating help  on how to do it properly do it.

As you can find in the mdn documentation, Array.find only returns the first element found in the array, which means your filteredPlayers signal only return a single instance of Player, hence why it is not iterable.
What you probably want to use is Array.filter which will return all matching element in a new array, which is probably what you wanted to do in the first place :
filteredPlayers = computer(() => {
  return this.players.filter(player => player.name.includes(this.search()));
})

Hope this helps.
